# Should I list by project or by accomplishment on my resume?

Tags: resume

I used to list my projects and the responsibilities I had on them, but more recently I just list my accomplishments at each company without mentioning specific projects.

Are either of these methods more effective than the other when searching for jobs?

Comment: Hi Ford, this is related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14389/should-i-refer-to-my-skills-in-terms-of-years-of-knowledge-years-of-experience. If it doesn't answer your question, consider editing your post with more details to help differentiate it and describe more about the job you're looking for, what kind of background you have, etc. Good luck! :)